# How to use bash shell for gnuplot to show Greek letter?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnuplot, plotting

I want to write a bash shell for gnuplot to produce figures automatically. But my figure includes Greek letters inside. I have known their ASCII number, how can I show them correctly in figures after running it?

For example, I wrote `set xlabel \"Cn = 0.74, \226 = 0.83 \"` in bash-script, but \226 does not show Greek letter \Gamma.

Actually I also want show n as C's subscript, but C_n does not work in bash-script for gnuplot, only shows C_n, how can I do this?

Comment: At this point in time, all terminals should be configured to use utf-8 by default (if they don't, set your locale immediately). Then, you can use unicode directly, as @Marco suggests (*if* the gnuplot terminal understands unicode - some of them might not - eps for instance, will cause problems).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just include as they are in utf8. Here's an
example:

```
#!/bin/sh

gnuplot <<EOF
set output 'output.pdf'
set term pdfcairo
set xlabel 'µΓ'
plot x
EOF

exit 0
```